# Was it ever made clear what happened with George's fur hat?

Tags: seinfeld

In *Seinfeld* S8:E8 (*The Chicken Roaster*)

> George leaves an expensive fur hat at his date in order to get another date when he comes back to pick it up.

However I can't figure out what happened with this item in the end. An internet search gave me [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/seinfeld/comments/v0hjq4/just_watched_s8e8_what_ever_happened_to_the_sable/) which contains some speculation, but not much else.

Was the answer to this question ever made clear, either in the show or by the writers? It's really bugging me!

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is, in all honesty. Sitcoms aren't generally known for their strict continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jerry Seinfeld was asked this question in a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1ujvrg/comment/ceitwhz/?context=3). His answer was less than illuminating.

> **Q:** *What really ever happened to George's Sable hat? (S8 E8)*
>
> **Jerry Seinfeld:** *It probably went back to the prop department where it came from.*

---

In-universe there were multiple possible thieves; **the date** (who was aware of the hat's value and might have sold it on or returned it to her store), **the maid**, the **various friends** that the date 'had over' the night before or **George himself** might have been lying about losing the hat because he didn't want to give it back to Elaine.

**We don't know and aren't ever told.**